# error when attempt to use equals method

Tags: equals, public, superclass, super, public-method

If two employee objects are the same, then I want to check if the same number is returned by the "getID()" method. I think I'm using the equals method wrong. I think something is wrong with the last line of code:

I have to keep this code:

```
public boolean equals( Object b )
{
  if ( ! (b instanceof Employee) )
    return false;
```

this is what I can edit:

```
(super.equals().getID()).equals(b.getID());
```

I get this error:

Compile Result: Error:
Employee.java:25: error: cannot find symbol

Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If "number" returned by getID() is a primitive

```
public boolean equals( Object b ){
   if (this == b) return true; 
   if ( ! (b instanceof Employee) )
      return false;
   final other=(Employee)b;
   return getID()==other.getID();
}
```

if number is Object

```
public boolean equals( Object b ){
   if (this == b) return true; 
   if ( ! (b instanceof Employee) )
      return false;
  final other=(Employee)b;
  return getID().equals(other.getID());
}
```

If you override equals make sure you override hashCode() as well.